# FluentWait default timeout is zero

Tags: java, selenium

What is the Default timeout for FluentWait when we dont specify like below, but i understand that default polling  is 500ms.

```
         FluentWait<WebDriver> wait=new FluentWait<WebDriver>(dr)
        //.withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
        //.pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

In timeout exception, I see-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException:(tried for 0 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

Does that mean we have default max timeout is 0 seconds.
When I went through [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html)- its says DEFAULT_SLEEP_TIMEOUT as [500L](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/constant-values.html#org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.DEFAULT_SLEEP_TIMEOUT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each FluentWait instance defines the maximum amount of time to wait for a condition, which is 500 milis bydefault. You already mentioned that from the docs, can also confirm same from [FluentWait.java](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.java)

```
  protected static final long DEFAULT_SLEEP_TIMEOUT = 500;
  private static final Duration DEFAULT_WAIT_DURATION = Duration.ofMillis(DEFAULT_SLEEP_TIMEOUT);
```

Timeout Exception logs `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException:(tried for 0 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)` because this is how exception is logged in console, i.e. withTimeout is getting evaluated in seconds and pollingEvery in miliseconds.

To visualize...

**Try 1:**

```
wait=new FluentWait<>(driver)
                .withTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(500))
                .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//someElementLocator")));
```

Exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //someElementLocator (tried for 0 second(s) with 2000 milliseconds interval)
```

**Try 2:**

```
wait=new FluentWait<>(driver)
                .withTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(1500))
                .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//someElementLocator")));
```

Exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //someElementLocator (tried for 1 second(s) with 2000 milliseconds interval)
```

Which confirms the way waiting timeout and polling interval is evaluated and then probably rounded of to floor (500 milis -> 0 seconds, 1500 milis -> 1 seconds) and logged to console.

Hope this clears !!

Comment: so both max Timeout and Polling are having default value as 500ms?

Comment: @J_Coder Yes ! simply comment out `.pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(2))` and see Exception in console it should be `tried for 0 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval`